# Looking for geographic topomaps without names of city

Tags: openstreetmap

for my next project I'm looking for maps, that contains only frontiers of countrys, lakes, hills ans rivers.

Can I get such kind of maps with the OpenStreet-API?

best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "OpenStreetMap API" provides map data, not map images. So, for the imagery you want, you either need to find a source that renders the style you want, or render your own.

I don't know of any services that provide exactly the render that you're looking for. However, it should be very easy to render your own tiles that do this - if you install [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and follow through the tutorial, you will find it very easy to delete layers from the default style until no names are included in the style.

Note that if you're planning on running a web service, you'll also need to serve your special new map tiles to your users.